# proof of ratio test (clarification)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]
[image]

This is the proof of ratio test in my text book. I understand that $(|x_M|r^{-M})r^n$ converges to zero. Then, as n goes to zero, $|x_n| $ converges to less than $0$, but how can it be possible??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Taking limits does not preserve *sharp* inequalities ($<$), only *weak* ones ($\leqslant$). So you should say $|x_n|$ converges to non-positive.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks !!